# How to detect tap on UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextField that has User Interaction Disabled. So if you tap on this text field, nothing happens. Normally to check if a text field was tapped Id try the delegate methods, but I cannot because user interaction is disabled. Is there any way I can check if the text field was tapped/touched? I change another element to hidden = no; when it is tapped so I was wondering if its even possible enabling user interaction.

Comment: As a side-note for future visitors: If you want to open a picker to select a value for your UITextField use the picker as the text fields inputView. That will automatically display the picker instead of the keyboard when the text field is tapped. Optionally use a UIToolBar in addition as the text fields inputAccessoryView which thens gets displayed above the picker (for the done-button etc).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Best option is to turn on User Interaction and disable edit action using delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     return NO;
}
```

You can call your method inside that function to detect tap.

Comment: Tried this too, but I have other text fields so this doesn't work.

Comment: It works - you just need to check if(textField == self.blockedTextField) return NO; else return YES;

Comment: Really strange - I used it so often - can you paste your code with that approach ?

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == birthdayTextField){
        birthdayDatePicker.hidden = NO;
        birthdayDatePicker.alpha = 0;
        return NO;
    }
    else{
    return YES;
    }
}

Comment: Are you sure that birthdayTextField is the right one ? Is it coming from storyboard or you manually assign value ? you can put a break point there and check if there is correct value under it. I'm quite positive it's the right approach.

Comment: A) I am sure B) The text field is nil, it gets set with the value the date picker returns

Comment: Josue, you have to make sure you set the delegate of your UITextField to the UIViewController with the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method.

Comment: The system calls this delegate method when the UITextField becomes first responder.  That can happen for other reasons besides a user tap.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe, you can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the superview, detect if the touch is inside the frame, and then do something.

### Detect touch if it is inside the frame of the super view

1. Create `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add that to the `UITextField`'s super view.
2. Implement the target selector and check if the gesture's state has ended.
3. Call your method.

#### Objective-C

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizeTapGesture:)];
[self.textField.superview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


- (void) didRecognizeTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) gesture {
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.textField.frame, point)) {
            [self doSomething];
        }
    }
}
```

#### Swift 3

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didRecognizeTapGesture(_:)))

    textField.superView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

private dynamic func didRecognizeTapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)

    guard gesture.state == .ended, textField.frame.contains(point) else { return }

    //doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Not called when tapping on the text field, only outside of it