# UITapGestureRecognizer not firing in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code in a custom `UIViewController`:

```
let tapDismissTextField = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTap))

func dismissTap() {

    print("Tap!")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapDismissTextField)
    self.friendsView.addGestureRecognizer(tapDismissTextField)
}
```

No "Tap!" lines are being printed, so the gesture recogniser isn't firing. What could be going wrong?

User Interaction Enabled is *true* accross all the views in this controller.

This view controller is embedded within a `UINavigationController` if that is of any help.

Comment: This is not the correct syntax, nor do I know how your code is not throwing an error, because there is no `UITapGestureRecogniser`, there's only `UITapGestureRecognizer` (with `z`, instead of `s`)

Comment: Apologies, those are all with a z

Comment: now, it's better. Spelling is really important.

Comment: Interesting, okay. I've left just self.view with the gesture recognizer, yet nothing is still printing. Could the problem lie outside this code?

Comment: posting an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign self only once your view is loaded.

```
var tapDismissTextField: UITapGestureRecognizer!
```

and in your viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tapDismissTextField = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTap))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapDismissTextField)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Move this line:

```
let tapDismissTextField = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTap))
```

inside `viewDidLoad()`, because `self` outside the methods / function / closures returns an `(NSObject) -> () -> YourClass()` (an NSObject), not your class, which actually is the owner of `view`.

**2.** I recommend leaving only one view the `GestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 1):

Add tapDismissTextField into viewdid load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 let tapDismissTextField = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissTap))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapDismissTextField)
    self.friendsView.addGestureRecognizer(tapDismissTextField)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to get actions on the `UITextField`. I guess you did change the `setUserInteraction` to `false` to prevent `UITextField` behavior. right? Thats why your gesture recognizer doesn't work.

So, you need to give as you see we are in a dilemma now. we want the gesture to work and we dont want the UITextField to behave normaly. We need to know what you wonna achieve to help you better.

**Info:**

> If you wonna show a custom view. for example `UIPickerView` set the
>   `inputView` property for your `UITextField` and remove your gesture
>   recognizer.

**Work around:**

> You can use the tap gesture on `UITextField` superview. And, try to
>   detect if the tap is inside the frame of the `UITextField`.
>   [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729523/how-to-detect-tap-on-uitextfield)

**Another work around:**

> Try to do your action on the `textFieldDidBeginEditting` delegate
>   method. And do some tweaks to disable the keyboard. may be setting the
>   `inputView` to nil.

**So, we need to know exactly what do you want to achieve to give you the proper solution.**